# In counting sort time complexity notation O(n+k), k is number of distinct elements?

Tags: sorting

Do I get right, that if we say that counting sort time complexity is O(n+k), this notation means that n is number of all elements to sort and **k is number of *distinct* elements**?

For example for array [ 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 5] 
n = 6 and
k = 4 ?

Comment: It is impossible to tell with the information we are given, since you haven't told us what $k$ is. Whoever stated the time complexity should also have explained what $k$ is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, he said that $k$ is number of [pairwise] distinct elements. And from his example it is clear: there are three 5's and all other elements are distinct, so without equal elements being sorted it is: [1, 3, 5, 7] and with them [1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7].

Comment: Who is "he"? Have you attended the same lecture? Or are you assuming the OP is male?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I should've used 'they', of course.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity of counting sort is $O(n + k)$ where $n$ is the size of array, and $k$ is the maximum element in the array, not the number of distinct elements.

For example if we have the array $A = \text{{1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8}}$ Let's say that for our array $n = 9$ because we have $9$ elements, and $k =8$ because our biggest element is $8$.

Now we create another array $B$ of size $k$ where for each number in the range $[1, k]$ we keep how many times in occurs in the array $A$. $B = \text{{1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2}}$.

Now we iterate through the array $B$ and for each index $i$ in $B$ we do exactly $B[i]$ iterations. We can see that sum of all numbers in $B$ equal $n$ so we do $k$ iterations in the first for and $n$ iterations in the second for.

In total the complexity is $O(n+k)$ where $n$ is the size of array and $k$ is the biggest element in the array.

Comment: so for array with elements [ 57, 59, 57 ], n = 3, k = 3 ((59 - 57) + 1), right? That is ((maxValue - minValue) + 1) ?

Comment: No, k is the range in which your numbers are, for the array [57, 59, 57], the numbers are in range [1, 59] because maxValue = 59, we can see that k = maxValue + 1, or in our case k = 59 + 1 = 60

Comment: In practice, software developers are not limited by inefficiences of some algorithms. So if I had to sort the birth years of a million people who are alive today, I would obviously determine the minimum and maximum of the values, and use k = (max - min + 1). Just because the inventor of an algorithm didn't think of this trivial improvement, and apparently created an algorithm that doesn't work with negative values, doesn't mean I have to follow that.

Answer (score 1):

No k isn't the number of distinct elements, instead it refers to the **range** which is given by **Maximum element** in the array + 1, i.e. 1 to max+1.

**In your case the value of k will be max element( i.e. 7) + 1= 8**

Comment: So if element values do not start from 1, for example for array with elements [ 57, 59, 57 ], n = 3, k = 3 ((59 - 57) + 1), right? That is ((maxValue - minValue) + 1) ?

Comment: no it will still be max element + 1, i.e. 59+1=60